# Get Cell Adress using VBA code when Vlookup is used

Tags: vba, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a code which lookup for a value in a range and get corresponding value from excel cell. But I also want to get the cell reference (cell address) of the next column. How can I get this?

My code for getting the value using vlookup is:

```
BCVE(i + 1) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(A(i + 1), MySheet.Range("B2:E8"), 2, False)
```

Now I need to get the cell address of the 4th column of the same row, which is in Column E. I tried the below Index and Match functions but no luck! It throws an error

```
"Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction Class" - Run-time error 1004.
```

I tried replacing Workfunction.Match with Application.Match but it doesn't work.

```
CellAdd1 = WorksheetFunction.Index(MySheet.Range("E2:E8"), WorksheetFunction.Match(A(i + 1), MySheet.Range("B2:E8"), 0), 4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worksheetfunction.Match should be used on a single column. You're using it on a multi column range.

For example, if your variable *CellAdd1* is a range object, you can find the cell in the 4th column of the same row with the following line, and refer to the cell's address with *CellAdd1.Address*:

```
Set CellAdd1 = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(A(i+1), MySheet.Range("B2:B8"), 0) +1, "E")
```

I added the '+ 1', since the function returns the relative position of an item in an array, and your array/range starts at row 2.